# How does Browser Vendor Server authenticate about the source of the web push notification?

Tags: javascript, service-worker, web-push

This is related to Service Workers. I use "webpush generate-vapid-keys" to generate a Public key and Private key, I pass the public key(convert from Base64 to Uint8Array) in the subscribe method which gives an endpoint and keys(object). On the server I pass three parameters to 'webpush.setVapidDetails"  function i.e 'mailto', 'public key' and 'private key'. I want to know how does the Browser Vendor Server know that the source of web push notification is the correct one. How does it(Browser Vendor Server) verify it?

Answer (score 0):

When you get a push subscription via [`push.subscribe`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PushManager/subscribe), the [`endpoint`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PushSubscription/endpoint) property must be secret. The browser assumes that anyone who knows this URL can post messages to this push subscription.

The browser will use a push service it trusts. Communication is authenticated via SSL.

If you use [`getKey`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PushSubscription/getKey), you get a public key. The browser keeps the private key. When it receives a push to the endpoint, it decodes the body using that private key.